# How to populate rules conditions in custom module Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

created a custom module like promotion sales rules in Magento for creating customers list. I am able to display conditions where I can select all customer's attributes and a value for those attributes.

[image]

These conditions are stored in table in serialized manner. But I cannot make them populate when I go to edit screen. Even though conditions were saved, it shows blank on edit screen

I looked at [How to integrate Conditions Block of Shopping Cart Rules in Custom module magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469659/how-to-integrate-conditions-block-of-shopping-cart-rules-in-custom-module-magent) but it didn't help

value of conditions in database is: 
`a:3:{i:1;a:4:{s:4:"type";s:32:"salesrule/rule_condition_combine";s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:9:"new_child";s:0:"";}s:4:"1--1";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:31:"amrules/rule_condition_customer";s:9:"attribute";s:9:"firstname";s:8:"operator";s:2:"{}";s:5:"value";s:1:"r";}s:4:"1--2";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:31:"amrules/rule_condition_customer";s:9:"attribute";s:5:"email";s:8:"operator";s:2:"{}";s:5:"value";s:5:"yahoo";}}`

Can anyone please guide how to display saved conditions?

Comment: Do you solve your problem ??
Please let me know I have the same requirement.